# SMTP outgoing Mail setup on linux using perl

Tags: linux, perl, smtp, sendmail

I am facing problem in sending mail using perl. When I put following command:
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($ServerName, Debug => 0); where $ServerName="localhost" . the $smtp is not set. It is null. Can anybody tell me the reason why it is not set appropriately . Since the same script is running on my other linux server.

Help is truly appreciated.

Thanks 
DD

Answer (score 2):

`Net::SMTP`, it appears, has rather underwhelming error handling.
The best you can do is:

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($ServerName)
            or die "Unable to connect to SMTP server '$ServerName'";
```

Even passing `Debug => 1` appears to do nothing when it can't create the object.

There hasn't been a new release of libnet (which includes Net::SMTP) in over three years.  There is a [developer release](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22_01/) from May 2010 which does appear to have some improvements: it [documents](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22_01/Net/SMTP.pm#CONSTRUCTOR):

`On failure undef will be returned and $@ will contain the reason for the failure.`

(The most recent proper release does not do this.)

If you're willing to try installing the developer release, you can improve your code to:

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($ServerName)
            or die "Unable to connect to SMTP server '$ServerName': $@";
```

Possible reasons your connection is failing:

- $ServerName not a valid host name
- No SMTP service running on $ServerName
- The server doesn't like the standard greeting, `localhost.localdomain`.  Pass `Hello => 'your.fully.qualified.host.name'` to the constructor.

You can try connecting to the SMTP server on the command line, on the host where you're trying to run this script:

```
$ telnet smtp.example.com
EHLO localhost.localdomain
quit
```

Comment: Thanks friend. Actually sendmail service was not running. It was very weird that debug msg was not throwing any error which made life painful to identity such a silly issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable debugging?

```
 $smtp = Net::SMTP->new(
 Host => 'mailhost',
 Hello => 'my.mail.domain',
 Timeout => 30,
 Debug => 1,
 );
```

Then have a look at what the debug output says.

Comment: Yeah I tried .. but unfortunately there is nothing coming out on console. I believe it writes through stderr which should be printed on console.  Would mind to help me to track the debug log?

Comment: OK, I'll try to reproduce your problem if I can, then post more.

Comment: Yes, apparently "Debug" does not report any errors. Weird :/.